# Bind Jetty to IPv6 address

Tags: jetty, ipv6

I am trying to bind Jetty to listen only to IPv6 address. I am using Jetty 7.4.2.v20110526.

my jetty.xml:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host">::1</Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8070"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

the error I get:

```
java.net.SocketException@3d3c4c09: Address family not supported by protocol family: bind; 
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:119)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:297)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
```

I have tried both `::1` and `[::1]`

How can I bind Jetty to IPv6 address? Is IPv6 supported by Jetty at all?

Comment: Jetty might be running under Java with `preferIPv4Stack=true` which disables IPv6.

Comment: @Steve-o I did not set this property. And earlier in tests I am creating a `ServerSocket` that listens to `[::1]:9999` without any problems. Java has nothing to do with it.

Comment: are you sure:  http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6230761

Comment: @Steve-o Yep, you are correct. Post it as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't found a solution, here it is. Change the NIO connector with the IO one. Instead of using "**org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector**" use "**org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector**" and the overall connector config will be:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8070"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

This way you will be able to access the webpage using both IPv4 and IPv6 address. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is invalid for the question.  The question clearly uses Jetty 7+ (with the org.eclipse.jetty namespace).  Your answer is only valid for Jetty 6.

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of the Sun JRE do not support IPv6 on NIO channels, so simply upgrade the JVM.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6230761