# free/open source proxy server in java with support for IPv6/https/user management

Tags: java, proxy, proxy-server

I am looking for a easy-to-configure Proxy server in Java, that is either free or opensource, and has the following features--

1. Support for IPv6.
2. Support for HTTPS
3. Addition/editing/deletion of users permitted to access the proxy server- through command line is a must, and if this can also be done through web forms that would be great.

Also, in connection with my query, I found one script named Muffin(http://muffin.doit.org/), but it is quite old...Will it take a lot of time to add IPv6 support to it?(I dont know what exactly has to be done to enable Muffin to support IPv6)- the last release date of Muffin is sometime in 2000!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is one solution.  They have a [proxy servlet](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/proxy-servlet.html) and should support [IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023523/bind-jetty-to-ipv6-address) and [SSL](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL).

> Addition/editing/deletion of users permitted to access the proxy server- through command line is a must, and if this can also be done through web forms that would be great.

This you would have to program yourself.  Here's some docs about [username/password stuff for Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Securing+Passwords).  Jetty has a password class which generates the auth lines for the [realm file](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Realms#Realms-HashUserRealm) yourself.  You could easily write a script for it.

Comment: The Jetty proxy servlet page has moved, now is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/proxy-servlet.html)

Comment: Is any project like https://hide.me/en/proxy in java ?