# Properly simulating an HTML action in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I need to mimic  a simple action in an HTML, this HTML actually works for my purpose but I have to make the same action in MVC ASP.NET.

Here is the HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM method="post" autocomplete="off" ACTION="https://<target IP>/auth/index.html/u">
        Username:<BR>
        <INPUT type="text" name="user" accesskey="u" SIZE="25" VALUE="">
        <BR>
        Password:<BR>
        <INPUT type="password" name="password" accesskey="p" SIZE="25" 
        VALUE="">
        <BR>
        <INPUT type="submit">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
```

This HTML gets two parameters "user" and "password" and posts them to an URI. I tried both "GET" and "POST" methods in my application but it didn't work.
Here is my controller in MVC ASP.NET:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string ArubaPost = "user=" + model.user + "&password=" + model.password;
            string ArubaURI = "https://<target IP>/auth/index.html/u";
            // this is to bypass the SSL certiface, not sure if it is needed
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

            // web request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ArubaURI);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ArubaPost);
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();


            string location = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location];
            return Redirect(ArubaURI + location);

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I also tried a "GET" action but the result for is is the same. I actually don't get any errors and when it is running in a browser I can see that the request is sent with status code 200 using Chrome inspect element.
This is a page that a network controller redirects all the traffic to it and then user have to enter user name and password. Then when it is sent via POST or GET, the network controller has to capture the parameters and verify them. In case of a successful verification, network controller redirects the user to the page he initially requested so he can surf the web. That simple HTML page fulfills all these but in MVC application I am redirected to the same login page again and again.
any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because the authentication cookie is not stored in the browsers. Instead it is handed to your server(MVC application).

You won't be able to achieve your goal with with your current approach. Because even if your server gives those cookies to the client(browser), it won't work since those cookies will send to your server only, not the `<target IP>` server.

Comment: Thank you, so what is the possible approach to do this?

Comment: I think you can use a http proxy server to fulfill your needs based on my guessing. You can check out answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276055/free-open-source-proxy-server-in-java-with-support-for-ipv6-https-user-managemen